# Django: Combine multiple saves into one database action

Tags: python, django

I have a function like this– is there a way to wrap this function so that both saves are combined into one?

```
    def foobar(self, created_at=None):
        changed = False
        if created_at:
            changed = True
            self. created_at = created_at
            self.save()
        if self.active:
            changed = True
            self.active = False
            self.save()
        return self
```

The reason I don't unindent `self.save()` is to avoid updating the `updated_at` field on my object if no change occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only perform a `self.save()` if the `changed` is `True` at the end of the `if` clauses:

```
def foobar(self, created_at=None):
    changed = False
    if created_at:
        changed = True
        self.created_at = created_at
    if self.active:
        changed = True
        self.active = False
    
    if changed:
        self.save()
    return self
```

So only if one of the two `if` clauses fires, this will set `changed` to `True`. Only when `changed` is set to `True`, we save the object. We here thus avoid an extra roundtrip to the database, if both `crated_at` and `self.active` are truthful.